# Error creating bean with name 'flightController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'flightrepos';

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have created 2 separate code in first code my code run fines while in other code i'm facing above issue.I will share both code plz help me out as i'm new to this spring and following some tutorial.

**CODE 1**

---

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepos;

@RequestMapping("/showReg")
public String showRegistrationPage() {
    return "registerUser";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@RequestParam("email")String email, @RequestParam("password")String password, ModelMap modelMap) {
    User user = userRepos.findByEmail(email);
    if(user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        return "findflights";
    }
    else {
        modelMap.addAttribute("msg", "Invalid try again");
    }

    return "login";
}}
```

**User bean class**

```
@Entity
public class User  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String password;

//getters and setters
}}
```

**Repository class**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

@Query(value = "select * from user u where u.email = :email", nativeQuery = true)
public User findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);

}
```

**CODE 2**

---

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class FlightController {

@Autowired
private FlightRepository flightrepos;

@RequestMapping("/findFlights")
public String findFlights(@RequestParam("from")String from, @RequestParam("to")String to,@RequestParam("departureDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern ="MM-dd-yyyy")Date departureDate, ModelMap modelMap ) {
     List<Flight> flights = flightrepos.findFlights(from, to, departureDate);
    modelMap.addAttribute("flights", flights);
    return "displayFlights";

}}
```

**Flight bean class**

```
@Entity
public class Flight {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String flightNumber;
private String operatingAirlines;
private String departureCity;
private String arrivalCity;
private Date dateOfDeparture;
private Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;
//getters and setters
}}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight, Long> {

@Query( value ="select * from Flight f where f.departurecity =:departureCity and f.arrivalCity =:arrivalCity and f.dateOfDeparture =:dateOfDeparture ", nativeQuery = true)
List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departurecity")String from, @Param("arrivalCity")String to, @Param("dateOfDeparture")Date departureDate);
}
```

i checked everything but now i'm getting below error

---

```
or creating bean with name 'flightController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'flightrepos'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flightRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List com.project.test.repos.FlightRepository.findFlights(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Date) but parameter 'Optional[departurecity]' not found in annotated query 'select * from Flight f where f.departurecity =:departureCity and f.arrivalCity =:arrivalCity and f.dateOfDeparture =:dateOfDeparture '!
```

Comment: camelcase typo here : change departurecity to departureCity

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your one of `@Param` of `findFlights()` method.

Change,

```
@Param("departurecity")String from
```

To,

```
@Param("departureCity")String from
```

Answer (score 1):

...parameter 'Optional[departurecity]' not found in annotated query...

- `f.departureCity`, not `f.departurecity`;
- `@Param("departureCity")`, not `@Param("departurecity")`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the same tuto I guess :p juste change `@Param("departurecity")` to `@Param("departureCity")`